# Android Studio duplicate generated files

Tags: android-studio, navigation

Android studio keeps creating generated classes, even though they already exist.

The problem has something to do with the NavigationArgs I guess but it always gives some error of duplication.

The only way that solves my problem now is to clean the entire project every time before I run the app.

Does anyone know how to fix this, how do I know which implementation is causing this error?

**Gradle Project**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.2.0-beta01"
        classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') {
            exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
        }
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Gradle Module**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.umbrella.budgetapp"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta05'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ronaldsmartin:Material-ViewPagerIndicator:1.0.4'

    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0'

    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
}
```

**Build output**

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/BuildConfig 2.java:6: error: class BuildConfig is public, should be declared in a file named BuildConfig.java
public final class BuildConfig {
             ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/BuildConfig.java:6: error: duplicate class: com.umbrella.budgetapp.BuildConfig
public final class BuildConfig {
             ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/IconsDirections 4.java:9: error: class IconsDirections is public, should be declared in a file named IconsDirections.java
public class IconsDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/GoalDetailsDirections 6.java:9: error: class GoalDetailsDirections is public, should be declared in a file named GoalDetailsDirections.java
public class GoalDetailsDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/GoalsReachedDirections 4.java:16: error: class GoalsReachedDirections is public, should be declared in a file named GoalsReachedDirections.java
public class GoalsReachedDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/PlannedPaymentsDirections 4.java:16: error: class PlannedPaymentsDirections is public, should be declared in a file named PlannedPaymentsDirections.java
public class PlannedPaymentsDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/PlannedPaymentsDirections.java:16: error: duplicate class: com.umbrella.budgetapp.Layouts.Fragments.PlannedPaymentsDirections
public class PlannedPaymentsDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/GoalsReachedDirections.java:16: error: duplicate class: com.umbrella.budgetapp.Layouts.Fragments.GoalsReachedDirections
public class GoalsReachedDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/GoalsPausedDirections 4.java:16: error: class GoalsPausedDirections is public, should be declared in a file named GoalsPausedDirections.java
public class GoalsPausedDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/ShoppingListItemsArgs 4.java:13: error: class ShoppingListItemsArgs is public, should be declared in a file named ShoppingListItemsArgs.java
public class ShoppingListItemsArgs implements NavArgs {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/GoalsActiveDirections 5.java:16: error: class GoalsActiveDirections is public, should be declared in a file named GoalsActiveDirections.java
public class GoalsActiveDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/DebtsBorrowedDirections 5.java:16: error: class DebtsBorrowedDirections is public, should be declared in a file named DebtsBorrowedDirections.java
public class DebtsBorrowedDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/ShoppingItemsArgs 4.java:13: error: class ShoppingItemsArgs is public, should be declared in a file named ShoppingItemsArgs.java
public class ShoppingItemsArgs implements NavArgs {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/ShoppingListItemsDirections 4.java:16: error: class ShoppingListItemsDirections is public, should be declared in a file named ShoppingListItemsDirections.java
public class ShoppingListItemsDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/StatisticsBalanceDirections 7.java:9: error: class StatisticsBalanceDirections is public, should be declared in a file named StatisticsBalanceDirections.java
public class StatisticsBalanceDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/DebtsLentDirections 5.java:16: error: class DebtsLentDirections is public, should be declared in a file named DebtsLentDirections.java
public class DebtsLentDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/ShoppingListItemsArgs.java:13: error: duplicate class: com.umbrella.budgetapp.Layouts.Fragments.ShoppingListItemsArgs
public class ShoppingListItemsArgs implements NavArgs {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/ShoppingListsDirections 4.java:17: error: class ShoppingListsDirections is public, should be declared in a file named ShoppingListsDirections.java
public class ShoppingListsDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/GoalDetailsArgs 5.java:13: error: class GoalDetailsArgs is public, should be declared in a file named GoalDetailsArgs.java
public class GoalDetailsArgs implements NavArgs {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/GoalDetailsDirections.java:9: error: duplicate class: com.umbrella.budgetapp.Layouts.Fragments.GoalDetailsDirections
public class GoalDetailsDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/StatisticsCashflowDirections 4.java:9: error: class StatisticsCashflowDirections is public, should be declared in a file named StatisticsCashflowDirections.java
public class StatisticsCashflowDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/StoresDirections 4.java:16: error: class StoresDirections is public, should be declared in a file named StoresDirections.java
public class StoresDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/IconsDirections.java:9: error: duplicate class: com.umbrella.budgetapp.Layouts.Fragments.IconsDirections
public class IconsDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/Fragments/GoalsPausedDirections.java:16: error: duplicate class: com.umbrella.budgetapp.Layouts.Fragments.GoalsPausedDirections
public class GoalsPausedDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateUserProfileDirections 10.java:8: error: class UpdateUserProfileDirections is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateUserProfileDirections.java
public class UpdateUserProfileDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateDebtDirections 4.java:9: error: class UpdateDebtDirections is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateDebtDirections.java
public class UpdateDebtDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateAccountDirections 4.java:9: error: class UpdateAccountDirections is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateAccountDirections.java
public class UpdateAccountDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateCategoryArgs 6.java:13: error: class UpdateCategoryArgs is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateCategoryArgs.java
public class UpdateCategoryArgs implements NavArgs {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateCategoryDirections 4.java:9: error: class UpdateCategoryDirections is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateCategoryDirections.java
public class UpdateCategoryDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateGoalDetailsDirections 9.java:8: error: class UpdateGoalDetailsDirections is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateGoalDetailsDirections.java
public class UpdateGoalDetailsDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateGoalDetailsDirections 10.java:8: error: class UpdateGoalDetailsDirections is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateGoalDetailsDirections.java
public class UpdateGoalDetailsDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdatePlannedPaymentArgs 8.java:13: error: class UpdatePlannedPaymentArgs is public, should be declared in a file named UpdatePlannedPaymentArgs.java
public class UpdatePlannedPaymentArgs implements NavArgs {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateGoalDetailsArgs 8.java:14: error: class UpdateGoalDetailsArgs is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateGoalDetailsArgs.java
public class UpdateGoalDetailsArgs implements NavArgs {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateCurrencyDirections 7.java:9: error: class UpdateCurrencyDirections is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateCurrencyDirections.java
public class UpdateCurrencyDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateTemplateArgs 7.java:13: error: class UpdateTemplateArgs is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateTemplateArgs.java
public class UpdateTemplateArgs implements NavArgs {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdatePlannedPaymentArgs 9.java:13: error: class UpdatePlannedPaymentArgs is public, should be declared in a file named UpdatePlannedPaymentArgs.java
public class UpdatePlannedPaymentArgs implements NavArgs {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateGoalDetailsArgs 9.java:14: error: class UpdateGoalDetailsArgs is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateGoalDetailsArgs.java
public class UpdateGoalDetailsArgs implements NavArgs {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateDebtDirections.java:9: error: duplicate class: com.umbrella.budgetapp.Layouts.UpdateFragments.UpdateDebtDirections
public class UpdateDebtDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateGoalSelectDirections 9.java:16: error: class UpdateGoalSelectDirections is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateGoalSelectDirections.java
public class UpdateGoalSelectDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateStoreArgs 7.java:13: error: class UpdateStoreArgs is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateStoreArgs.java
public class UpdateStoreArgs implements NavArgs {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateAccountArgs 7.java:13: error: class UpdateAccountArgs is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateAccountArgs.java
public class UpdateAccountArgs implements NavArgs {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdatePlannedPaymentDirections 7.java:9: error: class UpdatePlannedPaymentDirections is public, should be declared in a file named UpdatePlannedPaymentDirections.java
public class UpdatePlannedPaymentDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateUserProfileDirections 8.java:8: error: class UpdateUserProfileDirections is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateUserProfileDirections.java
public class UpdateUserProfileDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateRecordDetailsDirections 9.java:8: error: class UpdateRecordDetailsDirections is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateRecordDetailsDirections.java
public class UpdateRecordDetailsDirections {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateDebtArgs 9.java:13: error: class UpdateDebtArgs is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateDebtArgs.java
public class UpdateDebtArgs implements NavArgs {
       ^
/Users/XX/Documents/AndroidStudio/Projects/BudgetApp/app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug/com/umbrella/budgetapp/Layouts/UpdateFragments/UpdateShoppingListDirections 9.java:9: error: class UpdateShoppingListDirections is public, should be declared in a file named UpdateShoppingListDirections.java
public class UpdateShoppingListDirections {
       ^
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
100 errors

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: I just deleted the generated folder when switching flavors as a work around.  I have filed a bug with the navigation developers about this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BuildConfig is public, should be declared in a file named BuildConfig.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438157/buildconfig-is-public-should-be-declared-in-a-file-named-buildconfig-java)

Answer (score 0):

go to the menu and choose: Build -> Clean Project, and once done, Build -> Rebuild project

Answer (score 0):

If click Build -> Clean project or Rebuild project cannot fix the issue, there should be another issue lead to build failed. Fix other issue and rebuild could succeed.

Also check if there exists a real BuildConfig file in the package, delete it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

you may have created duplicate java files of same name and kind, check well and delete one.